# S3 giving someone permission to read and write

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've created a s3 server which contain a large number of images. I'm now trying to create a bucket policy, which fits my needs. First of all i want everybody to have read permission, so they can see the images. However i also want to give a specific website the permission to upload and delete images. this website is not stored on a amazon server? how can i achieve this? so far i've created an bucket policy which enables everybody to see the images

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [delegate access](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-user.html) to your bucket. To do this, the other server will need [AWS credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-security-credentials.html).

If the other server were an EC2 instance that you owned then you could do this easily by launching it with an IAM role. If the other server were an EC2 instance that *someone else* owned, then you could delegate access to them by allowing them to assume an appropriate IAM role in your account. But for a non-EC2 server, as seems to be the case here, you will have to provide AWS credentials in some other fashion.

One way to do this is by adding an IAM user with a policy allowing s3:PutObject and s3:DeleteObject on resource "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*", and then give the other server those credentials.

A better way would be to create an IAM role that has the same policy and then have the other server assume that role. The upside is that the credentials must be rotated periodically so if they are leaked then the window of exposure is smaller. To assume a role, however, the other server will still need to authenticate so will need some base IAM user credentials (unless you have some way to get credentials via identity federation). You could add a base IAM user who has permissions to assume the aforementioned role (but has no other permissions) and supply the base IAM user credentials to the other server. When using AssumeRole in this fashion you should require an [external ID](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-user_externalid.html). You may also be able to restrict the entity assuming this role to the specific IP address(es) of the other server using a policy condition (not 100% sure if this is possible).

Answer (score 0):

The **Bucket Policy** will work nicely to give everybody read-only access.

To give specific permissions to an application:

- **Create an IAM User** for the application (this also creates access credentials)
- **Assign a policy to the IAM User** that gives the desired permissions (very similar to a Bucket Policy)
- The application then makes **API calls** to Amazon S3 using the supplied access credentials

See also: [Amazon S3 Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Welcome.html)